# How to force detach a non-boot disk on all VM that's attached

Tags: google-compute-engine, disk

I have a shared read-only persistent disk that gets an update every month.

**How can I force all VMs attached to this shared disk to detach without passing to the command the list of instances?**

**How can I detach a Read-Only disk from all instances?**

A solution is to use `gcloud compute instances detach-disk INSTANCE_NAME --disk DISK` but I don't want to sequentially input a list of instance names that's attached.

Answer (score 1):

'gcloud compute instances detach-disk' doesn't have a 'force' option.

Bear in mind that detaching a disk without first unmounting it may result an error for the applications that are using the data. To unmount a persistent disk on a Linux-based image, ssh into the instance and run:

```
sudo umount /dev/disk/by-id/google-DEVICE_NAME
```

Once the device is detached you can use this script sample to run the 'gcloud compute instances detach-disk' command:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
zone="ZONE"
disk="DEVICE_NAME"
for i in $(gcloud compute disks describe $disk --zone $zone | grep "^-" | rev | cut -d "/" -f1 | rev)
do
  gcloud compute instances detach-disk $i --disk=$disk --zone=$zone
done
```

You can refer to this documentation[1] to get more information about the parameters of the command.

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/detach-disk

Comment: Maybe I've misrepresented my question. I don't want to input a list of instances rather GCP should have info on what instances is attached to this disk. Also the issues you propose is not an issue as there's no write operations allowed on a shared persistent disk. The only corruption is on programs that is reading.

Comment: Hello @Keto , I have updated my answer according to your question. 
I hope it is useful for you now :)